# How to pass state to static navigation in react native?

Tags: react-native, navigation

Need to pass state to navigation but `this.state.` not working, here is the code

```
      this.setState({
      demo:"some title"
    });
.....

 static navigationOptions = {
        headerRight:(<View>
          <Text>{this.state.demo}</Text>
                  </View>),
        };
```

Comment: want to display state value in top navigation bar.

Comment: need to fetch title of page and display on top

Comment: actually everything in above code. i have to access the state inside top navigation bar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176563/discussion-between-shibin-raju-mathew-and-justas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to set param something like this :

```
componentWillMount() {
     const {setParams} = this.props.navigation;
     setParams({demotxt:this.state.demo});
}
```

..

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation  }) => {

       const {state} = navigation;
           return {
               headerRight: (<View>
                 <Text>{state.params.demotxt}</Text>
                         </View>)
           }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified this line, you should call it like this.

```
<Text>{this.state.demo}</Text>
                  </View>),
```

Also, you should first declare your state in constant, and then pass the Const,
whenever setState is called. the render function will be invoked. Something like this.

```
 static navigationOptions = {
const title = this.state.demo;
            headerRight:(<View>
              <Text>{this.state.demo}</Text>
                      </View>),
            };
```